# Equivalent definitions of bounded sets in topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I want to show equivalence of following two definitions:

> *Definition 1:* A subset $U$ of a topological vector space is called bounded, if for every neighborhood of $0$ $V$, there is a scalar $s\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $U\subseteq sV$.

> *Definition 2:* A subset $U$ of a topological vector space is called bounded, if for every neighborhood of $0$ $V$, there is a scalar $s'>0$, such that $U\subseteq s'V$.

It is clear to me, that a Definition 2-bounded set is Definition 1-bounded, since any $s'>0$ in that definition is a scalar $s$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

To show that a Definition 1-bounded set is Definition 2-bounded set, is clear to me in the cases, when $s\ge 0$. In the case $s>0$, there is clearly $s'=s>0$. In the case $s=0$, it follows $U\subseteq\{0\}$, i.e. $U\in\{\emptyset, \{0\}\}$. Then one can find $s'=1$, since $\emptyset, \{0\}\subseteq V$.

However, in the case $s<0$ I am not sure, how to show it. The neighborhood of $0$ $V$ does not have to be balanced, so just taking $s'=-s$ does not work.

Any hint or help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $V$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ then so is $-V$. The map $x\mapsto -x$ is a homeomorphism with itself as an inverse.

Comment: Then replace $V$ with $V\cap (-V)$. Then $sV = |s|V$ so $|s|\geq 0$.

Comment: @Jakobian: This sounds like an answer.

Comment: But $U$ does not have to be in the intersection, does it? Do you mean the union of $V$ and $-V$?

Comment: @user408858 No, I mean the intersection.

Comment: Oh, you mean $V\cap (-V)$ is still a neighborhood of $0$ and from $U$ being bounded you can find a scalar $s''$, such that $U\subset s'' (V\cap(-V))= |s''|(V\cap(-V))\subset |s''|V$?